# How to remote debug on Windows application that is compiled on linux

Tags: eclipse, gdb, cross-compiling, gdbserver

I'm using Eclipse CDT Indigo. I read few advices how to use cross-debugging (Eclipse is on Windows, while compilation and debugging should be done on remote Linux machine). So far I was able to compile remotely on Linux, but I still can't figure out how to actually debug on remote machine. Is it possible at all (without Eclipse maybe)?

Btw Linux is a 64 bit CentOS and as far as I could find mingw64 is the only cross compiler available for it on windows. But from my experience it is sometime a bit too quirky. Is there a way to cross debug without a need for a cross compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You need a gdbserver compiled for target machine, and a gdb compiled for host machine runing the target executable.  If you have these two, then you can use wingdb add-on on visual studio to connect to gdb and gdbserver to remote debug from your windows machine.  I found the following links helpful:

http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/12173

http://www.wingdb.com/docs/Pages/wg_dev_elinux.htm